# href attribute not found when searching for elements by tagname in vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Using VBA, I am attempting to find the href attribute for weekly share price data of a given stock in the HTML of Yahoo finance. I need this to automate the download of the csv file containing the data. I have done my research, and have written the following code which I believe should find the URL. However, the code continues to end with an error. Is there a small error in my code or is there a bigger problem at hand.

I have searched for the parent of the hyperlink by classname to narrow the search which is successful. But when I search within this parent the code returns the error "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable".

I am new HTML scraping so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    Sub webpage()

Dim internet As Object
Dim internetdata As Object
Dim Find_Parent As Object
Dim Stock_Links As Object
Dim Link As Object
Dim URL As String

Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
internet.Visible = True

URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GTE.AX/history?period1=1341266400&period2=1499032800&interval=1wk&filter=history&frequency=1wk"
internet.Navigate URL

Do While internet.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set internetdata = internet.Document
Set Find_Parent = internetdata.getElementsByClassName("Fl(end) Pos(r) T(-6px)")
Set Stock_Links = Find_Parent.getElementsByTagName("a")

NextRow = 1

For Each Link In Stock_Links
    Sheet1.Range("A" & NextRow) = Link.getAttribute("href")
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
Next

MsgBox "Link Found"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you're using the InternetExplorer constant `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`, while using late binding.  Therefore, it sees it as an empty variable instead of its value, which is `4`.  This means that the `Do While/Loop` will always evaluate to `True`.  So you'll need to replace the constant with its value...

```
Do While internet.ReadyState <> 4
Loop
```

The other issue is with `getElementsByClass`.  It returns a collection of elements, where the indexing starts at `0`.  So you'll need to refer to one of the elements from that collection.  In this example, it looks like only the one element that you're looking for is returned.  So you'll need to refer to the first element, which has an index of `0`...

```
Set Stock_Links = Find_Parent(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
```